# Why can't I instantiate one of my Pages in a WP7 unit test project?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, windows-phone-7

I'm attempting to incorporate unit testing into a small WP7 audio recording app in an effort to familiarize myself with the concept. I've done some reading on the subject and am using the Windows Phone Toolkit Testing Framework. I'm new to the WP7 platform in general, and the concept of unit testing almost entirely.

I followed [Amit Chatterjee's example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amit_chatterjee/archive/2011/06/26/unit-testing-the-windows-phone-7-applications.aspx) unit test over at the MSDN blog, and believe I have my unit test project set up correctly. However, when I run the following test:

```
[TestMethod]
[Description("Should always have this. Check if MainPage is created without problems.")]
public void CheckMainPageNotNull()
{
   AudioRecorder.MainPage recorder = new AudioRecorder.MainPage();
   Assert.IsNotNull(recorder);
}
```

it fails. I know the Assert should never fail, and this is mostly a trivial test to see if I had the framework set up properly, which I clearly don't. AudioRecorder is the name of the primary project. The unit test reporter tells me that I ran into a XamlParseException that was unhandled:

> Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key AppNumberUpper [Line: 20
>   Position: 35] at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object
>   component, Uri resourceLocator) at
>   AudioRecorder.MainPage.InitializeComponent() at
>   AudioRecorder.MainPage...ctor() at...etc.

I have `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("AudioRecorderUnitTests")]` set in my `AssemblyInfo.cs` and am honestly stumped at what I have set up incorrectly. Does anybody have any insight, or any good examples of the Windows Phone Toolkit Testing Framework being used in a non-trivial example? Either would be much appreciated.

Comment: The assert will never fail. It looks kind of like an alibi-assert to at least have one.

Comment: @usr I know, it's meant to be a trivial test method to see if the framework is working properly, which I suppose it isn't. What do you mean by an alibi-assert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is likely a reference to a `StaticResource` that you've declared in your `App.xaml`. Since the Application class of the app being tested is not used, the reference cannot be resolved. Even if you did "new" it, it wouldn't work because `Application.Current` is your unit testing application.

I'd advise not testing your *views* (pages) from your unit test application, but your view models instead.

If that's not a possibility for you, you might want to consider declaring the same resources in your unit test project. To be honest, though, doing so makes them less and less like "unit tests" and more like a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: Yep, this was it exactly, and much more educational than my self-answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I finally figured out the cause, if not an actual solution. I had a custom ApplicationResource defined in the main project's App.xaml named AppNameUpper. It appears that when the Unit Test project attempted to parse this, it threw an exception. **Removing that resource and all references to it seems to have solved the problem.**

What I don't understand is how I'm meant to use ApplicationResources in conjunction with the Unit Testing framework, but that's a problem for another question, and more research, most likely.